# Binance Multithread Sockets - functions not called concurrently

Tags: python, sockets, stream, python-asyncio, binance

I have a code to receive data from binance, about current prices:

```
import asyncio
from binance import AsyncClient, BinanceSocketManager
import time
from datetime import datetime


def analyze(res):
    kline = res['k']

    if kline['x']: #candle is compleated
        print('{} start_sleeping {} {}'.format(
            datetime.now(),
            kline['s'],
            datetime.fromtimestamp(kline['t'] / 1000),
        ))
        time.sleep(5)
        print('{} finish_sleeping {}'.format(datetime.now(), kline['s']))


async def open_binance_stream(symbol):
    client = await AsyncClient.create()
    bm = BinanceSocketManager(client)
    ts = bm.kline_socket(symbol)
    async with ts as tscm:
        while True:
            res = await tscm.recv()
            analyze(res)

    await client.close_connection()


async def main():
    t1 = asyncio.create_task(open_binance_stream('ETHBTC'))
    t2 = asyncio.create_task(open_binance_stream('XRPBTC'))
    await asyncio.gather(*[t1, t2])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

How to make `analyze` function to be called concurently.
Binance sends info in the same time with both streams data (ETHBTC and XRPBTC)

But function `analyze` will be called only once previous `analyze` (sleep) is completed.

[image]

I wish function `analyze` is called immediately and independently.

Comment: ```await asyncio.sleep(5)``` not ```time.sleep(5)```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to put **analyze** in a thread. I think it will achieve what you want.

```py
import asyncio
from binance import AsyncClient, BinanceSocketManager
import time
from datetime import datetime
from threading import Thread

def analyze(res):
    kline = res['k']

    if kline['x']: #candle is compleated
        print('{} start_sleeping {} {}'.format(
            datetime.now(),
            kline['s'],
            datetime.fromtimestamp(kline['t'] / 1000),
        ))
        time.sleep(5)
        print('{} finish_sleeping {}'.format(datetime.now(), kline['s']))


async def open_binance_stream(symbol):
    client = await AsyncClient.create()
    bm = BinanceSocketManager(client)
    ts = bm.kline_socket(symbol)
    async with ts as tscm:
        while True:
            res = await tscm.recv()
            Thread(target= analyze, args = (res)).start()

    await client.close_connection()


async def main():
    t1 = asyncio.create_task(open_binance_stream('ETHBTC'))
    t2 = asyncio.create_task(open_binance_stream('XRPBTC'))
    await asyncio.gather(*[t1, t2])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

This should work as expected.

Comment: Adding threading to asyncio is not a lot different to just rewriting the routine without asyncio.